# Casting Generic to int

Tags: java, generics

**So in school we are making a project for graphic. I have this interface:**

```
package rasterdata;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface RasterImage<PixelType> {
    Optional<PixelType> getPixel(int c, int r);
    RasterImage<PixelType> withPixel(int c, int r, PixelType value);
    RasterImage<PixelType> cleared(PixelType pixel);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
}
```

**And this is the class which extends the interface and its `getPixel()` method:**

```
public class RasterImageBuffered<PixelType> implements RasterImage<PixelType> {
private final BufferedImage img;
private final Function<PixelType, Integer> toInteger;
private final Function<Integer, PixelType> toPixelType;
public RasterImageBuffered(final BufferedImage img,
                           final Function<PixelType, Integer> toInteger,
                           final Function<Integer, PixelType> toPixelType) {
    this.img = img;
    this.toInteger = toInteger;
    this.toPixelType = toPixelType;
}

@Override
public Optional<PixelType> getPixel(final int c, final int r) {
    if (c < 0 || c >= img.getWidth() ||
            r < 0 || r >= img.getHeight())
        return Optional.empty();
    return Optional.of(toPixelType.apply(img.getRGB(c, r)));
}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to implement a seed fill algorithm. To do that I need to compare the color of the pixel in Canvas (`color`) with the color which I will use to fill the polygon (`fillColor`).

**This is the seedfill class:**

```
public class SeedFill<PixelType> {



public RasterImage fill(final RasterImage<PixelType> img, final int x, final int y, PixelType borderColor, PixelType fillColor) {


    RasterImage<PixelType> result = img;

    PixelType color = (PixelType) img.getPixel(x,y);

        //this condition throws an error
        if((color & 0xffffff) == (fillColor & 0xffffff)){ 

        result = result.withPixel(x,y, fillColor);

        fill(img, x+1, y, borderColor, fillColor,bcgColor);
        fill(img, x-1, y, borderColor, fillColor,bcgColor);
        fill(img, x, y+1, borderColor, fillColor,bcgColor);
        fill(img, x, y-1, borderColor, fillColor,bcgColor);

    }


        return result;

    }


}
```

The problem is that when I want to compare the colors, error saying that I cant compare `PixelType` with `int` pops out. However casting It to int throws another error saying that I cant cast `PixelType` to `int`. Is there any way of comparing those two values?

Comment: As I said last time you asked this question: you can't do this with casting; you need an `IntFunction<PixelType>`.

Comment: It wasnt me actualy, but my friend. We have the same school project. I didnt read the anwers. Thank you, however I dont know how to implement it... @AndyTurner

Comment: @AndyTurner haven't noticed but please point out if there's a duplicate already.

Comment: I couldnt find the question anymore, so probably not @Mena

Comment: @Mena the question was deleted.

Comment: @AndyTurner Could you please provide me more information on how to implement the function?

Comment: What do you need to implement? You've already got `Function<Integer, PixelType> toPixelType`. That's not quite an `IntFunction<PixelType>`, but it does basically what you need. Just pass that into your `SeedFill`'s constructor, then invoke `toPixelType.apply` where you're currently doing your cast.

Comment: Okay, I have done this: `if ((toInteger.apply(nowColor)& 0xffffff) == (toInteger.apply(fillColor) & 0xffffff))` but its throwing `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Optional cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` bacause the img.getPixel() returns an Optional @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to answer as you don't advertise your `PixelType` class.

However:

`PixelType color = (PixelType) img.getPixel(x,y);`

This cast is wrong.

At the very least, you want to invoke `img.getPixel(x,y).get()`, othwerise you're casting an `Optional<PixelType>` as `PixelType`.

Secondly, depending on whether or not you have an appropriate getter in your `PixelType` class that returns `int`, you will want to use that when using bitwise operations with an hexadecimal literal.

Comment: So It should be more like `Optional<PixelType> color = img.getPixel(x,y); ? `

Comment: @nprogrammer as well. And you can then operate on your `Optional` to get the `PixelType` value or act upon if the `Optional`'s empty. But then again, the `PixelType` value itself will not be compatible with bitwise operations on literal integers. You'll need to somehow have a getter for whatever is in your `PixelType`.

Comment: Oh I see. However, there is no PixelType class in our project. Its just Generic type or maybe I am missing something out, but the class itself isnt in the package... @Mena

Comment: @nprogrammer you want to look at the API for whatever library you are using and see what `PixelType` holds in terms of methods / maybe even the source. I am not familiar with that myself. The bottomline is you can't just perform mathematical operations on most objects (with the exception of `Number` wrappers).

Comment: Okay, In an hour or so I will be able to touch the code again so I will look for the PixelType. Thanks by now. @Mena

Comment: So, I cant even get to PixelType because Its just a generic type. However when i hover the mouse on It, it says that It extends Object class. @Mena

Comment: @nprogrammer you need to find the documentation on that, and figure whether you can get any `int` value out of it that you can use for your own bitwise computations.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the comparison by adding:

```
private final Function<PixelType, Integer> toInteger;
```

Then the constructor:

```
public SeedFill(Function<PixelType, Integer> toInteger) {
    this.toInteger = toInteger;
}
```

And with this function I was able to call `toInteger.apply()` which made an `Integer` out of generic `PixelType`:

```
if ((toInteger.apply(nowColor.get()) & 0xffffff) != (toInteger.apply(borderColor))) {
        if ((toInteger.apply(nowColor.get()) & 0xffffff) != (toInteger.apply(fillColor))) {
```